# Nginx + PHP-FPM - WGET fails on api but CURL works

Tags: php, nginx

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out or understand what exactly is causing my api end point to fail in the manner it does. We run apache + mod_php. I'm working on converting it to nginx + php-fpm.

Everything is working when I test with curl.

`curl -u user:pass https://our.domain.com/api.php`

Everything is working when I use a URL.

`https://our.domain.com/api.php?u=USER&p=PASS`

But the thing seems to fail when using WGET from the command line.

`wget --http-username=USER --http-password=PASS https://our.domain.com/api.php`

It does however work if you offer it this.

`wget --auth-no-challenge --http-username=USER --http-password=PASS https://our.domain.com/api.php`

Here is my nginx configs:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 16;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 512;
}

http {

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    # Limit 6 API queries per minute
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=apilimit:10m rate=6r/m;
    # Set this to 'error' to log rate limit hits to error log
    limit_req_log_level info;
    # Status code for rate limit hits
    limit_req_status 503;

    fastcgi_pass_request_headers on;
    fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   45;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

My fastcgi_params file

```
fastcgi_param  HTTP_AUTHORIZATION $http_authorization;
fastcgi_param  AUTHORIZATION $http_authorization;

fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Server config file that is relevant. We have a bunch of rewrite rules for the URI to hit this point.

```
    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        limit_req zone=apilimit;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/socket;
    }
```

When I ran wget in debug, without the --auth-no-challenge, I can see it does the initial connect, says it wasn't challenged, it hits our php-fpm backend, which returns a 401. It issues a keep alive, and then sends the correct base64 encoded Authorization header and the request. But this time, nginx throws a 503. I can't seem to figure this out.

I can't figure out what is different between the non --auth-no-challenge and the one with it that makes it fail. Any help in what I can do on the. nginx side would be greatly appreciated.

Note: Updated with the current setup.

Comment: nginX always passes all HTTP headers to FastCGI (which PHP-FPM is). Why didn't you try passing username and password in the URL with WGET ?

Comment: Getting closer, I think I found a clue. I did a wget -d and saw that it said nginx didn't send a challenge. I issued another run but added --auth-no-challenge and it worked. Is there a way to spoof a challenge so that wget sends auth?

Comment: @IVOGELOV - I'm trying to support a legacy script that doesn't put the user/pass in the url as its deployed by the 1000s. That method does work in our more latest implementations.

Comment: Okay, wget behavior looks to be expected. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=446949

Comment: Well, without knowing anything about your PHP script, I would expect that if it does not receive the `Authorization` header and username/password are also missing in the URL - then it will respond with HTTP 401 error, right? And this will signal to WGET that it needs to repeat the request, but this time to include the `Authorization` header.

Comment: So it does appear to get the 401 from the php script, and it (wget) does attempt to auth. But I suspect nginx is trying to parse the auth perhaps, or its not getting to php-fpm, as I get a 503 in response to the retry. I thought maybe it was a api rate limit, and I bumped that up with no success either.

Comment: nginX will attempt to interpret your basic authorization only if you protect your PHP script as described in the documentation (https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/#configuring-nginx-and-nginx-plus-for-http-basic-authentication) - otherwise nginX will not attempt to interfere. You will need to enable the debug log of nginX to see why you get 503 error.